# How to run code immediately after user registers for notifications in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I have an app that sets a local notification upon the press of a button. Upon the first press of that button, I register for local notifications. My question is: after the user responds by either disallowing or allowing notifications, am I able to somehow detect when the system's notification registration alert has dismissed (and run code to set or not set the local notification).

Please note that checking UIUserNotificationTypes in currentUserNotificationSettings() isn't what I'm looking for. I want to be able to run code immediately after the user chooses to either allow or disallow notifications. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time a "system" dialog is presented, `applicationWillResignActive` will be called in your App Delegate (and the corresponding `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` will be posted via `NSNotificationCenter`).

When the dialog is dismissed `applicationDidBecomeActive` will be called (and `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` will be posted).

If you set a boolean property before you request notification permissions, you can check this in `applicationDidBecomeActive` and if it is true, take a reasonable guess that the notifications dialog has just been dismissed.

If you are using the iOS 8+ method `registerUserNotificationSettings` then you can simply check the result in your app delegate `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:` method.

Comment: Thanks for your help Paulw11. Haven't really dealt with NSNotificationCenter before, but after some research and trial/error, this works like a charm! As a beginner trying to learn programming, I can't thank you enough for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Paulw11 said, you should implement for  ios >= 8.0

```
optional func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:

to check the full documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1